# Augmenting Types, method not found

Tags: javascript

I am trying one of the examples from the book 'Java Script the Good Parts'. Find below the code.

It throws an error saying Number has no method integer. Could you please help me understand the problem.

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

Number.method('integer', function () {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this);
});
```

After running the above code, it attaches a method integer to Number.prototype

```
Number.prototype.integer
```

It displays the function.

```
Number.integer
```

It says undefined.

```
Number.integer(10);
```

I get - Number() { [native code] } has no method 'integer'

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I tried by replacing ceiling with ceil. Still it does not work.

Comment: _"I tried by replacing ceiling with ceil."_ - That wasn't the main problem, but you should definitely make that change, "ceil" is the correct method name.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling it like `(3.14).integer()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the method to the prototype assigned to `Number` *instances*, you're not adding it to the `Number` function itself.

So to use it, you call the method on an *instance* of `Number`, like this: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iFagAHU/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/iFagAHU/1/edit)

```
var n = 3.1415;
var i = n.integer();
console.log("i = " + i); // "i = 3"
```

Or with a numeric literal: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ujOxAl/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ujOxAl/2/edit)

```
console.log(3.1415.integer()); // "3"
console.log((3).integer());    // "3"
```

Note that in the second line above, I had to put the `3` on its own in parens; otherwise, the JavaScript parser thinks the `.` is a decimal point rather than a property accessor.

---

Side note: Extending the prototypes of predefined types with enumerable properties can be a bit hazardous. I've never seen any significant problems when people extend `Number` or `String`, but there are *major* problems if you extend `Array` or `Object`, so I would stay away from doing that.

---

Side note 2: In my examples above, I've also corrected the name of `Math.ceil` (it's `ceil`, not `ceiling`).

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I needed to create an instance of Number in order to use the method which is attached to the prototype but not to the Number function itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `method` function *(which is taken from Javascript the Good Parts)* which you are adding to the prototype of `Function` helps you define a method on given class or type so that all instances or objects of that type inherit that method.

Two problems in your code:

1. You are calling `integer` as if it were defined on the class or constructor function `Number` itself which is not the case, it is defined on the prototype of `Number`. If the function was actually defined on `Number` itself, it would have been defined like this:

   ```
   Number.integer = function() { /* Implementation */ };
   ```
2. You are passing a parameter to the function *(i.e. `Number.integer(10)`)*, although in the body of the function you aren't dealing with that number, nor you have declared the `integer` function to accept any parameters. I guess you are confused that this number is being refereed to by the `this` keyword inside the function but that is not correct.

The `method` function allows you to define a method on a given type and you can benefit from it like this:

```
var a = 10.3; // Now a is a Number instance and so it inherits the integer() method
console.log(a.integer()); // call the method on a
```

You can even call it directly on literals and they will be wrapped automatically by the interpreter, like this:

```
console.log((32.543).integer());
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I needed to create an instance of Number in order to use the method which is attached to the prototype but not to the Number function itself.